# ¿Cómo evitar crear una objeto si ya existe en la base de datos en Django?

Tags: python, django

En mi proyecto estoy creando una vista en la cual un usuario puede crear objetos de Seguros Medicos.
Este modelo solo contiene dos campos:

- la compañia aseguradora
- el pais de donde proviene esta compañia

Me gustaria evitar crear una instancia de una aseguradora si esta ya existe en la base de datos.

Estoy usando try,except,else para esto. Sin embargo, no logro evitar que esta instancia se cree.

## Formularios

```
class InsuranceCarrierForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InsuranceCarrier
        fields = '__all__'
```

## Modelos

```
class InsuranceCarrier(models.Model):

    ORIGIN_CHOICES = (
        ('HND', 'Honduras'),
        ('NIC', 'Nicaragua'),
    )

    company = models.CharField('company', max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, help_text='Insurance Carrier')
    country = models.CharField('country', max_length=100, blank=False, null=True, help_text='Insurance Carrier origin',
                               choices=ORIGIN_CHOICES, default=None)
```

## Vista

```
def add_insurance_carrier(request):
    insurance_carrier_form = InsuranceCarrierForm
    context = {'insurance_carrier_form': insurance_carrier_form}
    template = 'patients/insurance_add.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        insurance_form = InsuranceCarrierForm(request.POST)
        if insurance_form.is_valid():
            try:
                InsuranceCarrier.objects.get(company=insurance_form.cleaned_data['company'],
                                             country=insurance_form.cleaned_data['country'])
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                insurance_form.save()
            else:
                context['unique_error'] = '*Blah'
                return render(request, template, context)
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con el código que muestras no veo por que te crea el nuevo registro.

Puedes intentar que genere el error al nivel de base de datos.

No me quedó claro si quieres como único el nombre

```
company = models.CharField('company', ... ,unique=True)
```

ó ambos

```
class InsuranceCarrier(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['company', 'country']
```

Con esto toma como único el par `company` y `country`

Answer (score 2):

Te hace falta agregar un constraint a tu modelo para indicarle que deseas que la combinación de company y country sea única como menciona @loki. Después crear migraciones y migrar cambios.

Luego tendrás que modificar este bloque de código:

```py
            try:
                InsuranceCarrier.objects.get(company=insurance_form.cleaned_data['company'],
                                             country=insurance_form.cleaned_data['country'])
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                insurance_form.save()
```

Puesto que ahora si intentas crear un objeto "duplicado" te levantara otro tipo de error:

```py
            try:
                insurance_form.save()
            except IntegrityError:
               context['unique_error'] = '*Blah'
               return render(request, template, context)
```